# Angular2 Observable HTTP Data not filled

Tags: http, angular, request, observable

I´m fairly new to Angular2 and want to load data from a JSON-file.
I read the AngularIO Article and did the tutorial, but i still need some help.
I splitted the "getting Data" into an apiService which loads data and a component, whicht gets the data from the apiService.

Because it´s simpler, for this question I want to load the data directly to the component without the apiService.

This is the component:

```
export class StatusComponent implements OnInit {

    private status = {};
    private error: string;

   constructor(private router: Router, private variables: Variables, private apiService: ApiService, private http: Http) {
        if (!this.variables.getIsLoggedIn()) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getStatus();
    }

    getStatus() {
       this.http.get('../app/apiFiles/status.json')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.status = data},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
      );
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.status));
    }
}
```

This is JSON:

```
{
  "status": {
    "timercount": "0",
    "reccount": "0"
   }
}
```

In the component, the `getStatus()` is correctly load, and goes through without an error, but the variable i fill `status` isn´t filled.
After the `getStatus()` the variable is still `{}`.
Moreover, the output of  `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.status));` is `{}`.

I hope someone can help me and solve it !
Thank so much!

Answer (score 2):

That's because `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.status));` is executed after http call is done. Have in mind that all http calls are **asynchronous** methods. Try this:

```
getStatus() {
   this.http.get('../app/apiFiles/status.json')
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => { this.status = data},
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log(this.status);
  );
}
```

You'll see this will print your result because `() => console.log(this.status);` is executed after http call is successfuly completed.

Comment: Thanks, but no, this was not the solution :/

Comment: The Solution was to use `this.status = data.status `, then the data is loaded... ;)
But thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is this:

```
getStatus() {
       this.http.get('../app/apiFiles/status.json')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.status = data.status},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
      );
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.status));
    }
```

So, you have to use `data.status`, because the JSON file begins with "status" ;)